# Randomness vs. optimization

Tags: optimization, random-variable

Given the number of users of an application was 70 in total, it's [my understanding that research shows](http://www.measuringusability.com/five-users.php):

> Five users is the number of users needed to detect approximately 85%
>   of the problems in an interface, given that the probability a user
>   would encounter a problem is about 31%.

Thing is that over time, it seems likely that a given user's abilities to detect problems compared to other users would likely become more predictable. Is this true, and if not why? If it is true, what would be the best formula for knowing when to switch from random selection to optimal selection?

**Note:** Please note that this question is roughly understood by me, and it's very possible that there's a fundamental issue with the premise and/or gaps in the assumptions provided. If so, please comment and I'll attempt to address any concerns, questions, etc.

Comment: Its not necessarily five users, it really depends on the device. There is a method of assessing how many users are needed through a bootstrapping approach, but the paper has not yet been published (look for Borsci et al forthcoming)

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: Is this the paper, "[The Bootstrap Discovery Behaviour (BDB): a new outlook on usability evaluation](http://www.springerlink.com/content/9x1188631072v116/abstract/)"? I've found what appears to be an older version of the research here in PDF, "[Cost of a Usability Evalution: Bootstrap Discovery Behaviour Model](http://www.iadisportal.org/digital-library/mdownload/cost-of-a-usability-evalution-bootstrap-discovery-behaviour-model)".

Comment: no - i work with Simone (Borsci) and he's currently getting internal feedback on the paper I referred to. You could email him simone.borsci@brunel.ac.uk if you'd like to know more

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: Never got a reply when I emailed Simone back on March 26. Do you know if the paper has been published, and if so, do you have the title of the paper, or a link to it? Thanks! (Just sent Simone a follow up email, so it's possible he missed the email back in March.)

Comment: i would probably sign my real name and give some details about your background if you wish to get a reply (pretty good advice for most academics I find).

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: Thanks for the quick followup.  To be honest, you're the first person to ever request I disclose my name, background, etc; even if I did it would not be of use since I have a very generic name and no academic/professional background.  Further, I contact/work with people all the time via the internet without them having any idea who I am.  I respect your request, but will pass on the offer.  Again, thanks!

Comment: I meant in your email to my colleague. I don't really have an issue with it, but others do (people worry that their research will be stolen etc). I don't understand it, but that appears to be the way it is.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: So, Simone was kind enough to forward the paper after getting the followup email. Since I can only speak for myself, I would never steal others work. Again, thanks!